# MySQL Select Feature for More than one product

Tags: mysql

I have the following data in **feature_variant_product** I want to select **feature_id** that match for multi **product_ids**

[image]

I have the following query a the moment which shows all features for product_id 1,2

```
SELECT * FROM feature_variant_product WHERE product_id IN (1,2)
```

With the following output

[image]

I want the query to only show feature_id if both 1 and 2 have it

Comment: [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) so far?

Comment: you mean to say that you want to show the result whe  feature_id will have  1 and 2 ??

Comment: @sandeep_kosta I want feature_id's that both product_id 1 and 2 have.

Comment: @DevDonkey tryed the following query, SELECT * FROM feature_variant_product WHERE product_id IN (1,2)

Comment: you want to show the feature id when it will have 1 or two ??

Answer (score 1):

SELECT Distinct feature_id FROM feature_variant_product WHERE product_id IN (1,2) // for distinct feature_id

Comment: Thanks for response, this groups them together. I only want to see features that both product_id 1 and 2 have.